# calculate different values for one variable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this data model

```
{
    {
        "student":"a",
        "grade": "A"
    },
    {
        "student": "a",
        "grade": "B"
    },
    {
        "student": "B",
        "grade": "C"
    },
    {
        "student": "B",
        "grade": "C"
    }
}
```

How can I group by students and say student a have 1 A and 1 B, student b have 2 C? I am new to mongo, I tried look up aggregate and match but did not know how to implement it correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into the `$group` aggregation operator, as well as additional operators related to it that allow, for example, conditional incrementing of values. Be sure to carefully look at related examples as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by grade and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) accumulator. Then to output the student, use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) and add it in the projection:

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {} // match any student
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: "$grade",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      student: {
        $addToSet: "$student"
      }
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
      "student": 1,
      _id: 0,
      total: 1
    }
  }
]);
```

Note : the student field in the result data can be named whatever you want, the name comes from the `$group` clause (same goes for the "total" name). I also chose not to return the `_id` in the projection.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will look like this:

```
db.students.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$student", grade:"$grade", count:{$sum:1}}}

])
```

And if you have nested arrays, change it to:

```
db.students.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$parent.student", grade:"$parent.grade", count:{$sum:1}}}

])
```

where `parent` is the parent element in the nested array.